# main usage of properties(get,set)

Tags: c#

Hi all we can assign a value or return a value many other way.. so sometimes we are doing by properties(get,set).. can any one tell me main use of properties..

thanks 
saj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties encapsulate internal logic. They are the public interface and allow you to check values, apply rules and enable to change internal implementation.

This is in contrast to exposing internals directly.

For example:

```
public int myField; // exposes implementation - BAD BAD BAD
```

Is better implemented:

```
private int myField;
public int MyField
{
   get {return myField;}
   set {myField = value;}
}
```

You can now change the internal `myField` and not affect other code outside the class. You can add logic to the setter, to the getter and more.

If you don't have any logic associated with member access, you can use automatic properties:

```
public int MyField {get; set;}
```

The compiler will generate a backing field automatically.

Comment: hi oded i'm new to this concept.. could u elaborate

Comment: hi oded you made the field myField as private.. so if i want to access from outside of the class/scope.. or can we access?

Comment: That's the point. It is now **not** exposed. You access it using the public property.

Comment: hi oded so you are saying by default properties are public?

Comment: One could argue that just exposing the private variable through a property does not really change much about exposing the inner workings of your class (even if you *may* have done something more tricky). Get properties are fine to exposing state to outer world, but changing stuff might be better done through methods that take a complete set of parameters and changes the class content in an atomic and consistent way. That said I create lots of setters because they are quite handy to use.

Comment: @Albin - it is about being _able_ to change internals without _having_ to change externals at the same time.

Comment: @saj - No, properties are not public by default. But they don't make much sense as private...

Comment: @Oded: Yeah, but if you have exposed most of your private fields as public properties, you have a hard time doing anything radical.

Answer (score 5):

Properties provides an abstraction for getting and setting state. I.e. they allow you to define what getting and setting means in the actual context. A common example of how this is used on setters is to notify subscribers when state change. This cannot be done if you expose public fields.

Comment: This answer compares properties mainly to fields, but not to methods. I think it is a valid question to ask why we need properties if we could as well just declare a getter and setter method (I honestly don’t know the answer to that, it seems to be purely aesthetic...)

Comment: @Timwi: We could just as well have declared getter and setter methods, but since C# supports the concept of properties it would be a tad weird to do so IMO. That being said, there are some obvious drawbacks to the way properties are implemented. They look like fields, but they have methods semantics.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the advantages of encapsulation, we prefer using properties with get and set accessors among many other ways, because they provide a clear and practical syntax.

The syntax:

```
public int Field{ get; set; }
```

is more clear than this:

```
private int field;
public int GetField(){
     return field;
}
public void SetField(int field){
     this.field = field;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just say that using getters and setters on private fields, give you more control over those fields. You may want to allow only authorized entities to access that variables.. so you can put a check in the getField method. You may want to allow,  only to read values and not update them , then you can have only getters and no setters. so basically with methods exposing the private fields , you have more control over them.